# Use DISTINCT multiple times on the same dataset have any effect?

Tags: sql

I have a sql query with several joins and then saves it in a temporary table, well summarized it is something like this:

```sql
SELECT
a.Id,
a.Nome,
b.Telefone,
c.Email
INTO #TEMP
FROM TabelaA A 
INNER JOIN TabelaB B ON ...
LEFT JOIN TabelaC C ON ...
```

Then a subquery with dynamic sql is used to make different queries based on this data from the temporary table, something like this:

```sql
SET @query = 'WITH SUBQUERY (
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY
Id,
Nome,
Telefone,
Email
)'


SET @query = @query + 'SELECT DISTINCT ...'
```

My question is, does invoking DISTINCT over and over on the same subset make any difference or is it just doing it once?

Comment: At a high level, no, applying the same filter to a given dataset more than once should not change anything.  But your current query is confused and is using `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`, which is unusual.  Sample data would help your question.